# Gate driver using switches UC3842 PWM Controller

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, driver, boost, pspice

I have prepared a crude model of boost controller using PSpice simulator of  [UC3842 IC](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/uc3842.pdf)

[image]

Gate driver has Ron and Roff as 1 and 100meg respectively (S3 and S5)
and Vout will go to external mosfet or a switch in boost converter.
[image]

But I dont get 16V when S3 is on it gives a large spike of 16V and settles to 8V during turn on and turn off of the switches.

[image: Gate output]

Spikes at the output of gate driver.

Is there any specific way of building divers using switches what i should take care or improve this? 
I am not obtaining required duty cycle due to this behavior.

[image]

[image]

[image]

I have attached images of my work, body diode on the switches S3 and S5 reduced the spikes.

But output voltage didn't match with the duty cycle is there anything where I have to concentrate on?

Comment: Diagram is worse than unreadable, sadly. NO labels show and the components look like modern art :-(. (Have a look at your images). If you can greatly improve this we can help. || GET gate drivers need drive currents in the hundreds of mA to maybe a few amps range - both high and low. If you answer this comment AFTER having fixed the image I will be notified and can give guidance.

Comment: I have updated the question please let me know if there anything required or unclear. I have snipped each blocks of pwm controller.

Comment: S3 & S5 appear to have complementary enable conditions. Change so both are ON=1.

Comment: May I know why do we need so, since we need voltage drop across when its off Roff= 100 meg i gave it complementary conditions

Comment: (1) Try what I suggest and see what happens. (2) You have two complementary drive signals. They are either 10 or 01. If the driven switches do not have complementary enables then when you send 10 you get eg high on and low off. When you send 01 you get low on and high off. BUT with complementary enable conditions when you send eg 10 you get BOTH switches on and when you send 01 you get BOTH switches off. This is not what you want. (3) See 1.

Comment: I see you've seen my answer. What happens when you change the enable conditions on S3 OR S5 as I suggest. Can you see why?

Comment: My circuit don't converge when I do that...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. This worked as switch Gate Driver which can be used as a Generic Gate Driver with a drop of approximately 1V drop from the drive voltage.
2. First stage of inverter switches are used as voltage drop devices for the second stage with inputs as complementary inputs and with High Roff and Low Ron.
3. Body diodes are inserted at the output to avoid spikes (higher/ lower clamps).

[image: Gate Driver]